# ERD - How to show an entity can have a list of an attribute

Tags: erd

I tried searching google but couldn't find the answer.

Let's say my entity is "Question", and a question can have many "topics".

How do i represent that in an ERD?

rectangle represents an entity.
oval represents an attribute.
etc.

For example i made a question (this one) and i have 2 topics (erd and er-diagrams).